# Blender save files wrong

Tags: modeling

I'm really new to Blender. I have problem with saving .blend files. When I save file in Blender, and try to open in another Modeling app, it's just nothing. I think this is of ngons, but i don't know what to do. http://www.mediafire.com/file/12u2csyge7ff7d9/file.

Comment: The other software likely doesn't support blend files. Check what files formats the target software supports. Blender can export to other formats through *File > Export*. More exporters can be installed as add-ons.

Comment: Unity supports .blend files.

Answer (score 0):

Blender saves the files correctly.

Ngons have nothing to do with this (always search for the meaning of words before using them).

Different applications support different formats of 3d objects and object attributes. No single application is compatible with the many different formats that exist.

To open the files in a different app, then you have to export in a format that the other app can deal with.

When you convert an object to another format, not all attributes (textures, animations, constraints, modifiers, armatures or simulations) will be saved a s part of a format that does not support such attributes.

Comment: read the following link as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Thanks for link susu. I had the same problem. When I took the .blend file and imported it to the Unity, I had the same error as in the link you sent. I am very new at Blender and did not really understand what was going on and asked this stupid question. But I have another question, how to export UV coordinates with your mesh into Unity. I changed the Path Mode to Copy, but it changed nothing.

Comment: I see just black mesh, and I can't change material of mesh.

Comment: This site works different than "forums", don't ask more than one question on the same page. Create a new question in a different page.